# Help me verify that my PCB track widths are suitable for my application

Tags: pcb, current, pcb-design, trace

This was my first time designing PCBs, so I apologize in advance if this sounds dumb...

I'm making an ATX PSU adapter for old computers that didn't use this standard. There wasn't much electrical engineering involved, it's pretty much a "converter" (i.e. re-routing) board. I had calculated my track widths based on 2 oz copper layers. Now that I got quotes back from PCB manufacturing houses, I'd rather use 1 oz copper layers because it's much much cheaper.

Here's what I'm working with:

- 120 VAC: max 6 A power draw (per track). My tracks are 3 mm (120 mils) wide.
- 5 V (motherboard): max 3 A (per track). Tracks are 2 mm (80 mils) wide.
- 12 V (motherboard): max 5 A (per track, worst case scenario, probably less in real life). Tracks are 2 mm (80 mils) wide.
- 5 V standby: 1.25 A, 1 mm (40 mils) wide.
- "Molex" power connectors: I can't seem to find an actual max current spec, but 16 AWG can work up to 10 A apparently. The tracks are 2 mm (80 mils) wide.

**Should I make my tracks wider or is this sufficient?**

I've seen that temperature rise is an important factor. Bear in mind that the PCBs will be cooled by a massive fan.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT: I already tried online calculators and obtained the following results (please check the widths I have vs. temperature rise). I don't know how much these can be trusted... 80°C for the HD connector doesn't seem right.**

[image: calculations]

Comment: Use this tool https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see edited post for details.

Comment: Increase the HD track width to 100 mils and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll make that 3mm (120mils) and that should be more than enough. According to 4PCB, 8Amps with a 25 degC temperature rise corresponds to a 3mm track.  What about the rest though? Is it ok?

Comment: For the FR4 board, such a temperature rise should not be a problem. And try to keep a distance between 120 VAC track at more than 2mm apart.

Comment: Great to hear. This board can actually be used with 240VAC too. The smallest distance between line and neutral is 3.5mm. Just to be extra sure, I'll add another .5 mm (4mm total should be enough, right?)

Comment: 4mm will be enough.

Comment: Naaahhhh, an 80 °C temperature rise on the HDD connector can't be true.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the trace with you can use this [Calculator](https://www.7pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.php). You can set different parameters included maximum temperature rise.

You should also ensure enough trace clearance for the 120 VAC section!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see edited post for details.